# Allure Report unknown unknown - NoN%

Tags: python

I am newbie to allure and Pytest. I have created testcases inPpytest framework. For reporting I am using allure. when I execute the  `allure serve <Reporting foldername>` command report shown as **NoN%.** Is there any plugin missing?

I did not understand where I went wrong. Can anybody assist me to resolve this issue?

When I run

```
pytest --alluredir=Reports
```

JSON files are created instead of XML.

Then, I executed

```
allure generate allure-reports
```

inside Report folder.
When I run `allure serve allure-reports`, report shown as Non% even though 5 test cases passed.

Report image:

[image]

Pytest report image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). Also you should consider asking programming questions on [so]. Your question doesn’t seem to be limited to Ubuntu, so you might get better responses there.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412552/allure-report-unknown-unknown-non